# Moving an image in KineticJS using touch events

Tags: javascript, cordova, kineticjs

I want to make a Map, the user should Scroll it using touch events, zoom in and out using touch gestures.
Here am using the touchstart to set the dragging flag to true, then i use touchmove to calculate the delta in the coordinates and move the layer (map layer) accordingly, then finally i use touchend to set the dragging flag to false.

the problem is it's not working, been banging my head for few hours so far can't get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/map.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header of #main</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="core/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js">      </script>

        <script defer="defer">
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'content',
                width: 300,
                height: 200
            });

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                image: imageObj,
                width: 106,
                height: 118
                });
            layer.add(yoda);
            stage.add(layer);
            };
            imageObj.src = 'image/map-04.png'

            var dragging = false,
            lastX = 0,
        lastY = 0;

            imageObj.on('touchstart', function() {
                var touchPos = stage.getPointerPosition();
                dragging = true;
                lastX = touchPos.x;
                lastY= touchPos.y;
            });

            imageObj.on('touchmove', function() {
                var touchPos = stage.getPointerPosition();
                if(dragging){
                var dx = touchPos.x - lastX;
                var dy = touchPos.y - lastY;
                layer.translate(dx,dy);
                lastX = touchPos.x;
                lastY = touchPos.y;
                }
            });

            imageObj.on('touchend', function() {
                dragging = false;
            });
            stage.add(layer);
</script>
    </div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer of #main Page</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your imgObject is not a kineticjs image, yoda is a kineticjs image, here is a fix with some changes:

http://jsbin.com/miqoxese/1/edit

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.js"></script>

    <script defer="defer">
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'content',
            width: 300,
            height: 200
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 106,
            height: 118,
              draggable: true
            });
          yoda.on('dragstart', function(){
            console.log("dragging"); // see console for result
          });
        layer.add(yoda);
        stage.add(layer);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/9/9/d/11949855741697952186small_house_01.svg.med.png';

       // stage.add(layer); // no need to add again
    </script>
```

Now you need to attach your touchstart touchend etc events to yoda, not to imgObject which is part of the DOM, not the canvas.